# Prettify JSON class

Tags: c++, c++11, json, formatting

It's not much, but I tried employing some of the things I learned yet never really got to use, since that kind of code isn't really needed where I work (for the most part). I tried making it as much C++11 as I could. I would like to know if I messed up somewhere, maybe something could have been done better, or maybe you got some tips to improve readability?

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

class JSONPretify : public std::string{

public:

    JSONPretify(std::string j){
        this->assign(j);
        pretify();
    };
    JSONPretify(std::string j, bool colon_space){
        this->assign(j);
        pretify();
        if(colon_space)
            insertColonSpaces();
    };
private:
    void pretify(){
        std::regex var = std::regex(R"((\".+?\".*?(?=\{|\[|\,|\]|\}))|(\d+?))");
        long it = 0;
        int depth = 0;
        while(it < this->size() && it != -1){
            regex_pos pos_tab = findRegexFirstPosition(it, var);
            long pos_comma = this->find(",", it);
            long pos_obj_start = this->find("{", it);
            long pos_obj_end = this->find("}", it);
            long pos_array_start = this->find("[", it);
            long pos_array_end = this->find("]", it);
            long old_it = it;

            unsigned long work_with = find_lowest(std::vector<long>{pos_tab.pos, pos_comma, pos_obj_start, pos_obj_end,pos_array_start,pos_array_end});

            switch(work_with){
                case(TAB):{
                    std::string insert = generateSpaces(depth);
                    this->insert(pos_tab.pos, insert);

                    it = pos_tab.pos+insert.size()+pos_tab.length;
                    break;
                }
                case(COMMA):{
                    std::string insert = "\n";
                    this->insert(pos_comma+1, insert);

                    it = pos_comma+1;
                    break;
                }
                case(OBJ_START):{
                    std::string insert = "\n";
                    this->insert(pos_obj_start+1, insert);
                    it = pos_obj_start+insert.size();
                    depth+=1;
                    if(pos_obj_start-1 < 0 || pos_obj_start > this->size()) continue;

                    if(this->at(pos_obj_start-1) != ':'){
                        std::string extra = generateSpaces(depth-1);
                        this->insert(pos_obj_start, extra);
                        it+=extra.size();
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case(OBJ_END):{
                    std::string insert = "\n"+generateSpaces(depth-1);
                    this->insert(pos_obj_end, insert);
                    depth-=1;
                    it = pos_obj_end+insert.size()+1;
                    break;
                }
                case(ARRAY_START):{
                    depth+=1;
                    std::string insert = "\n";
                    this->insert(pos_array_start+1,insert);
                    it=pos_array_start+insert.size();
                    break;
                }
                case(ARRAY_END):{
                    depth-=1;
                    std::string insert = "\n"+generateSpaces(depth);
                    this->insert(pos_array_end,insert);
                    it=pos_array_end+insert.size()+1;
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    break;
                }
            };


            if(it == old_it)
                break;
        }
    };

    void insertColonSpaces(){
        long pos = 0;
        while(pos < this->size() && pos != -1){
            pos = this->find(":", pos);
            if(pos == -1 || pos >= this->size()) break;
            this->replace(pos,1, " : ");

            pos+=3;
        }
    }
    struct regex_pos{
        long pos;
        long length;
    };
    std::string generateSpaces(int l){
        std::string r="";
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            r+= "    ";
        }
        return r;
    }
    regex_pos findRegexFirstPosition(long start_pos, std::regex rx){
        long at = -1;
        long l = 0;

        std::string ss(this->begin()+start_pos, this->end());
        std::smatch m;

        std::regex_search ( ss, m, rx );

        for (unsigned i=0; i<m.size(); ++i) {
            at = m.position(i);
            l = m[i].str().size();
            break;
        }
        if(at != -1) at += start_pos;
        return {at,l};
    }
    template<typename T>
    unsigned long find_lowest(std::vector<T> outof){
        unsigned long lowest_it = 0;
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < outof.size(); i++){
            if((outof[i] < outof[lowest_it] && outof[i] != -1) || (outof[lowest_it] == -1 && outof[i] != -1)){
                lowest_it = i;
            }
        }
        if(outof[lowest_it] == -1)
            lowest_it = outof.size()+1;
        return lowest_it;
    }

    enum positions{
        TAB = 0,
        COMMA = 1,
        OBJ_START = 2,
        OBJ_END = 3,
        ARRAY_START = 4,
        ARRAY_END = 5
    };
};
```

[Github link](https://github.com/Borisas/cpp-json-pretify/blob/master/JSONPretify.h)

Comment: @Borisas Do you _really_ need to inherit from 'std::string' ?? OR you just did it to reduce some typing ? Either case, its not a good practice.

Comment: I do see lots of unnecessary copies..in constructor, you can just `move` the copied string...can you use `std::min_element` instead of calling `find_lowest`, which also copies the vector, instead of taking by rvalue reference or const reference..

Comment: `generate_spaces` function can be just `return std::string(' ', count);`

Comment: `std::regex var = std::regex(R"((\".+?\".*?(?=\{|\[|\,|\]|\}))|(\d+?))");` XKCD said it well [Regular Expressions](http://xkcd.com/208/) Which just leads to [100 problems](https://xkcd.com/1171/)

Comment: @arunmu i wanted it to be a single call to "prettify" the json. At the time this seemed as the most obvious way to accomplish this while also having it somewhat readable.  (why i inherited std::string, trying to rewrite so i don't have to inherit)

Comment: @LokiAstari I understand that it's not a good way of solving all problems, but in this case it seemed like the most reasonable way to find specific occurrences without writing a ton of code that would literally do the same thing.

Comment: Another thing is usage of `long` type everywhere. Consider using types like `std::size_t`, `std::string::size_type` (this is what actually `string::find` returns). And, by the way, if not found, `find` returns `std::string::npos`, which is not necessarily `-1` as your code assumes.

Comment: I stay corrected: npos *is* specified to be `-1`.

Comment: Spelling: 'pretify' should be 'prettify'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for editing the question. I have few ideas how you might want to polish your code.

### std::string base class

It caught my eye that `JSONPretify` is derived from `std::string`. Generaly speaking STL containers are not meant for such use case. Specificaly it is a good idea if you are deriving from a base class to check that it has virtual destructor. `std::string` does not have `virtual` destructor.

See e. g.
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP52-CPP.+Do+not+delete+a+polymorphic+object+without+a+virtual+destructor

### interface

I would go even further and suggest that as you don't need to model any state, keep any data or invariant simple function might be better interface.

```
std::string pretify(const std::string& j, bool colon_space = false);
```

### separation of interface and implementation

In order to be able to hide all hairy details from users of your code you might separate it into interface and implementation. The most common form is iterface only header file (e. g. prettify.hpp) and implementation source file (e. g. prettify.cpp). You then might leave all definitions and implementation details for prettify.cpp. To separate it from the rest of your code (even that you are only linking to) you might use either anonymous namespaces or internal linkage functions (surprisingly this is other meaning of keyword `static`).

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

### find_lowest

I would try to avoid implementation of this algorithm and use `std::string::find_first_of()` and/or `std::min_element()`.

If you decide to stick with it then you still might simplify it by not making it a template as there is just single call to it. You also probably don't want to copy the argument vector so reference might be more appropriate:

```
unsigned long find_lowest(const std::vector<long>& outof){
```

### work_with

I would recommend using scoped enum (great C++11 extension) and distinquishing between such enum and integers.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum [Scoped enumerations]

All it takes is new `positions` definition:

```
enum class positions{
```

and change to values usage:

```
case(positions::TAB):{
```

I am perplexed by this

```
positions work_with = find_lowest(std::vector<long>{pos_tab.pos, pos_comma, pos_obj_start, pos_obj_end,pos_array_start,pos_array_end});
```

because you are assigning position to `work_with` but checking content in `switch`. Is it correct?

### variables

This is kind of subjective opinion but omitting some helper variables might increase readability.

```
            case(COMMA):{
                std::string insert = "\n";
                this->insert(pos_comma+1, insert);

                it = pos_comma+1;
                break;
            }
```

shortened to

```
            case(COMMA):{
                this->insert(pos_comma+1, "\n");

                it = pos_comma+1;
                break;
            }
```

For those variables that you create and don't intend to change I would definitely use `const` to let know the compiler about your intention and let it actually check that you don't accidentally violate that.

```
const std::regex var = std::regex(R"((\".+?\".*?(?=\{|\[|\,|\]|\}))|(\d+?))");

const regex_pos pos_tab = findRegexFirstPosition(it, var);

const std::string insert = generateSpaces(depth);
```

### insertColonSpaces

Basically you are replacing one string with another.

This question might give some hints (e. g. `boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy` or using `std::regex`).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343190/how-do-i-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-with-another-string

### generateSpaces

Unless I have overlooked something it is the same as

```
return std::string(l * 4, ' ');
```

Check `std::string` "fill" constructor here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

### for() { break; }

This loop

```
    for (unsigned i=0; i<m.size(); ++i) {
        at = m.position(i);
        l = m[i].str().size();
        break;
    }
```

looks more like a simple condition

```
    if ( m.size() > 0 ) {
        at = m.position(0);
        l = m[0].str().size();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm currently rewriting and improving the code. Transferring it from a class into a namespace function. But I noticed that this either reduces readability tremendously or the namespace has a bunch of functions that are only used for the JSONPrettify part. That's why I opted to use a class with private and public members, so the user would only see the relevant part - JsonPretify and I inherited std::string so there wouldn't be multiple function calls to "prettify" the json string. 

So the question - Any tips to put it in a namespace, but also make it readable?

Comment: 2nd comment, because i ran out of characters.

Should i be a namespace within a namespace? (Have the JSONPrettify in a namespace and create a namespace within that namespace that would have the functions that are needed for JSONPrettify function. _boy that sounds complicated_ )

Comment: Also - can i add edited (improved?) versions here somehow?

Comment: @Borisas You are very welcome. 1. I added new part to the answer "separation of interface and implementation" 2. It would render all answers and discussion chaotic. Creating new question would seem better to me. http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/editing-question-after-answer http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question

Comment: So if I understood correctly - you suggest separating it into a header and source file, instead of just single header file. Which is the way i would usually do, but I wanted to make it as easy to implement as possible (which was also the reason for inheriting std::string) and you have to compile .cpp files which is more work than just writing a #include (if i understand things correctly). 

I added an edited version. I put it in a namespace, got rid of the class, added a sub-namespace that has everything that JSONPrettify needs. This seemed to be in line with your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but the character limit gets me every time.

I wanted it to be a single header file mostly because it's a single function, so implementing it, the way i see it, should be easy and fast. But I might be wrong this just seems like it makes the most sense

I of course did much more than just move functions and variables. The only thing I didn't do (i think) was remove the std::string insert; variable, because i want to have a unified way of inserting and getting the length of insertion across all cases.

Comment: @Borisas I really think you should create another question for the edited version as this page would be a mess.

Comment: I created a [follow up](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132834/pretify-json-class-followup) thread.

Answer (score 4):

#### Inheritance

At least in theory, the inheritance you've used here is somewhat dangerous--it's possible to convert a `JSONPretify` to a `std::string` implicitly, and probably more importantly, to convert a `JSONPretify *` to a `std::string *` implicitly. If a user ends up deleting a `JSONPretify` via a `std::string *`, you get undefined behavior.

Since `std::string` doesn't have any virtual functions, you're not overriding any virtual functions. That means you're not gaining *much* by using inheritance. If you really want to use inheritance anyway, I'd at least consider using private inheritance. This prevents implicit conversion to the base class, removing (most of) the danger. A user could still convert to the base class using an explicit cast, but at least you're forcing them to do it explicitly.

#### Use of `this->`

Although some languages require that you use `this->` (or equivalents such as `self`) to refer to member variables/functions, C++ does not--and doing so adds a great deal of visual noise that distracts and hurts readability. It should be avoided unless truly necessary (which it's not here).

#### Variable names

That leads directly to looking at some of the variable names, such as `insert`. Picking good names is often difficult, but there's not such a shortage of names that we need to have a single statement using the same name for both a function and a variable, such as: `this->insert(pos_obj_start+1, insert);`. I'd rename the variable to something like `leader` or perhaps `prolog`.

#### Consider default arguments to reduce repetition

For example, you have two nearly identical constructors:

```
JSONPretify(std::string j){
    this->assign(j);
    pretify();
};
JSONPretify(std::string j, bool colon_space){
    this->assign(j);
    pretify();
    if(colon_space)
        insertColonSpaces();
};
```

I'd at least consider collapsing these down to one with a default argument:

```
JSONPretify(std::string j, bool colon_space = false){
    this->assign(j);
    pretify();
    if(colon_space)
        insertColonSpaces();
};
```

This will normally retain the same behavior--you can invoke it as:

```
JSONPretify(input);
JSONPretify(input, false); // same as above
JSONPretify(input, true);
```

#### Add a little safety

Although it's *probably* not a big deal, I'm guessing you don't normally want to allow implicit conversions from `std::string` to `JSONPretify`, so you might as well mark the constructor that can be invoked with only one argument as `explicit`.

```
explicit JSONPretify(std::string j, bool colon_space = false) {
    this->assign(j);
    pretify();
    if(colon_space)
        insertColonSpaces();
};
```

#### Avoid boolean parameters

When looking at client code, I doubt it's immediately obvious how `JSONPretify(foo, true)` differs from `JSONPretify(foo, false)` (i.e., it's not obvious what the Boolean is controlling). I'd consider using an `enum` instead:

```
enum class colons { tight, spaced };

explicit JSONPretify(std::string j, colons spacing=colons::tight) {
    this->assign(j);
    pretify();
    if(spacing == spaced)
        insertColonSpaces();
};
```

This would be invoked something like:

```
JSONPretify(foo, colons::spaced);
```

or:

```
JSONPretify(foo, colons::tight);
```

...which seems quite a bit clearer, at least to me (though some might prefer a name other than `tight`).

#### Spelling

I hesitate to even mention this, but it seems like the class name should have two "t"s: `JSONPrettify`.

Comment: Thanks i'm trying to improve the code in accordance to your review/comments/tips!

Answer (score 3):

Nit: minor, but a function definition doesn't need a ";" after the "}"

```
     pretify();  
};
```

And not on switch statement scope either!