# Pretify JSON class -followup

Tags: c++, c++11, json, formatting

This is a follow up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132790/pretify-json-class). This is an improved version in accordance to comments, suggestions and reviews.

Is the namespace implementation proper? is the code readable? I didn't want to split it into header and source files, because i want to make this single function quick to implement. Maybe i left something out? Maybe the JSONPrettify_specifics should be an anonymous namespace?

```
namespace boris {

    namespace JSONPrettify_specifics{
        enum class Colons{
            TIGHT,
            SPACED
        };
        enum class Position{
            TAB = 0,
            COMMA = 1,
            OBJ_START = 2,
            OBJ_END = 3,
            ARRAY_START = 4,
            ARRAY_END = 5
        };
        struct RegexPos{
            size_t pos;
            long length;
        };

        std::string generateSpaces( int l ){
            return std::string(l*4, ' ');
        }
        long lowestOf( std::vector<size_t> of ){
            std::vector<size_t>::iterator result = std::min_element(std::begin(of), std::end(of));
            return std::distance(std::begin(of), result);
        }

        void insertColonSpaces( std::string & j ){
            std::regex colon = std::regex(R"(\s*?\:\s*?(?=\S))");
            j.assign(std::regex_replace(j, colon, " : "));
        }
        RegexPos findRegexFirstPosition( const std::string & json, const long start_pos, const std::regex rx ){
            size_t at = -1;
            long l = 0;

            std::string ss( json.begin()+start_pos, json.end() );
            std::smatch m;

            std::regex_search( ss, m, rx );

            if ( m.size() > 0 ) {
                at = m.position(0);
                l = m[0].str().size();
            }
            if( at < json.size() ) at += start_pos;
            return {at,l};
        }
    }

    std::string JSONPrettify( const std::string & json, boris::JSONPrettify_specifics::Colons spacing=boris::JSONPrettify_specifics::Colons::TIGHT ){

        using namespace boris::JSONPrettify_specifics;

        std::string pretty      = json;
        const std::regex var    = std::regex(R"((\".+?\".*?(?=\{|\[|\,|\]|\}))|(\d+?))");

        long it                 = 0;
        int depth               = 0;

        while( it < pretty.size() ){

            RegexPos pos_tab        = findRegexFirstPosition( pretty,it, var );
            auto pos_comma          = pretty.find( ",", it );
            auto pos_obj_start      = pretty.find( "{", it );
            auto pos_obj_end        = pretty.find( "}", it );
            auto pos_array_start    = pretty.find( "[", it );
            auto pos_array_end      = pretty.find( "]", it );

            long old_it             = it;

            Position work_with;

            {
                std::vector<size_t> _temp = { pos_tab.pos, pos_comma, pos_obj_start, pos_obj_end,pos_array_start,pos_array_end };

                auto at = lowestOf(_temp);


                if(_temp[at] > pretty.size())   break;


                work_with = static_cast<Position>(at);
            }

            switch( work_with ){

                case(Position::TAB):{
                    std::string insert = generateSpaces(depth);

                    pretty.insert( pos_tab.pos, insert );

                    it = pos_tab.pos+insert.size()+pos_tab.length;
                    break;
                }

                case(Position::COMMA):{
                    std::string insert = "\n";

                    pretty.insert( pos_comma+1, insert );

                    it = pos_comma+1;
                    break;
                }

                case(Position::OBJ_START):{
                    std::string insert = "\n";
                    pretty.insert( pos_obj_start+1, insert );

                    it = pos_obj_start+insert.size();

                    depth+=1;

                    if(pos_obj_start-1 > pretty.size()) continue;

                    if(pretty.at(pos_obj_start-1) != ':'){
                        std::string extra = generateSpaces( depth-1 );
                        pretty.insert( pos_obj_start, extra );
                        it+=extra.size();
                    }

                    break;
                }

                case(Position::OBJ_END):{
                    std::string insert = "\n"+generateSpaces( depth-1 );
                    pretty.insert( pos_obj_end, insert );

                    it = pos_obj_end+insert.size()+1;

                    depth-=1;
                    break;
                }

                case(Position::ARRAY_START):{
                    std::string insert = "\n";
                    pretty.insert( pos_array_start+1,insert );
                    it=pos_array_start+insert.size();

                    depth+=1;
                    break;
                }

                case(Position::ARRAY_END):{
                    std::string insert = "\n"+generateSpaces( depth-1 );
                    pretty.insert( pos_array_end,insert );
                    it=pos_array_end+insert.size()+1;

                    depth-=1;
                    break;
                }

                default:{
                    break;
                }
            };

            if(it == old_it)
                break;
        }

        if(spacing == Colons::SPACED)
            insertColonSpaces(pretty);

        return pretty;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? I am getting runtime error. http://ideone.com/kE6Y4D

Comment: My bad. I fixed it. http://ideone.com/3C9RjR ; The problem was that I didn't check wether all the positions are bad/impossible ( > size() )

Answer (score 2):

### Regarding your questions

- Is the namespace implementation proper?

  1. More common names for namespace with implementation details are `detail` or `impl`.
  2. `Colons` is part of your "public" interface as it is a type your function expects to be provided by user (or client). Therefore I wouln't put it into your iplementation interface.
- Maybe the JSONPrettify_specifics should be an anonymous namespace?

  1. You probably don't want to use unnamed namespace in your header. See e. g. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL59-CPP.+Do+not+define+an+unnamed+namespace+in+a+header+file

I still think splitting the code between header and implementation is a superior solution but I respect your decision not to do it.

### Correctness

I realized that you are probably not expecting characters as ',', ':' or '{'? in json values.

Think about this json example: `{ "name": "John[]"}`

If you want more general json parser you might need to rethink some approaches.

Colons could be in values as well.

```
if(spacing == Colons::SPACED)
    insertColonSpaces(pretty);
```

Commas (and others) could be in values as well.

```
auto pos_comma          = pretty.find( ",", it );
```

### Readability

I would name integer other than `l` here as it is rather similar to `1`.

```
    std::string generateSpaces( int n ){
        return std::string(n*4, ' ');
    }
```

### Implementation

### lowestOf() & Positions

I think I finally understand your `lowestOf` usage. Sorry it had taken so long! There are corner cases to be addressed (what to do if you don't find next special character). I have some ideas how to simplify it - in the end you probably don't need `Positions` enum at all.

```
        // try to find next position of interest
        const RegexPos pos_tab = findRegexFirstPosition( pretty,it, var );
        const std::string::size_t other_pos = pretty.find_first_of(",{}[]", it);

        // if nothing interesting was found we are done
        if(pos_tab.pos == std::string::npos && other_pos == std::string::npos) {
            return pretty;
        }

        // just be carefull that not every position was necessarily found
        const std::string::size_t work_with_idx = std::min(pos_tab.pos, other_pos );

        if(work_with_idx == pos_tab.pos) {
            pretty.insert( pos_tab.pos, generateSpaces(depth) );

            it = pos_tab.pos+insert.size()+pos_tab.length;

        } else {

            switch( pretty.at( work_with_idx ) ){       

                case ','    : {     
                    // ...
                }
                case '['    : {
                    // ...
                }

                // ...
            };
        }
```

### avoiding regex copying

You might avoid copying the regex here

```
RegexPos findRegexFirstPosition( const std::string & json, const long start_pos, const std::regex rx ){
```

by using a reference

```
RegexPos findRegexFirstPosition( const std::string & json, const long start_pos, const std::regex& rx ){
```

### missing headers

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/YM84RH Here is the changed version. I changed the regex so it would find less common names/values like "John[]". I also added some references (to the regex you offered and to the lowestOf - where i pass a vector. lowestOf basically finds the closest position to the iterator (last position it worked with), so if all the positions are impossible the find returns std::string::npos, which is unsigned long -1, so it's larger then max size of the string (in theory) and lines (81;91) were created to detect if maybe all positions are incorrect-impossible as to avoid range errors.

Comment: Is my usage of lowestOf still incorrect (considering it manages to avoid range errors)? If I understood you correctly then the biggest problem is readability - the code doesn't explain itself  So it's not good enough. Am I right to interpret it this way?

Comment: @Borisas I am not sure your code is working correctly in case for example `pretty.find( ",", it )` returns -1. If I understand it correctly `lowestOf` then returns 1 (index of `pos_comma` in params) and that is probably not ok. Is it so?

Comment: But `pretty.find( ",", it )` wouldn't return -1, it would return -1 in unsigned long (since `.find` returns in size_t and size_t is unsigned long) which is... 4294967295 (at least in [this case](http://ideone.com/bSaSGu)  ), and in theory a string shouldn't be that long.  I would think that the max value of unsigned _long_ should be _too long_ for event the _longest_ imaginable string, by any _stretch_ of the imagination. sorry. or am I unaware of some case in which size_t would become a non unsigned type?

Comment: I'll be more precise, since i'm late to edit it. If `std::string::find` fails to find a value it returns `std::string::npos`as documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and `std::string::npos`is always unsigned and -1 so it's max value as documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/), which in theory should never be more than the length of the string. So lowestOf should never fail. Also if it failed none of my code would work and it would throw an `std::out_of_range` exception which isn't something I could miss in this case

Comment: @Borisas Sorry, my mistake, haven't realized it's unsigned.